# I need help in using Analytical or Aggregate function in my query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT pid,oid,
item_to_buy AS item_purchase_count
FROM
(SELECT distinct A.pid,A.oid,
B.item_to_buy
//row_number()over(partition by A.oid order by item_to_buy) as RNK
FROM table A
JOIN table B
ON A.product_id=B.product_id
WHERE date='2022-03-03'
AND A.oid IS NOT NULL
AND A.oid=34721248
)
```

When I run the above query, I'm getting values which I have mentioned below:

```
PID          OID      ITEM_PURCHASE_COUNT

93012594908 10021248    NULL
93012594908 10021248    0
93012594908 10021248    1
```

I want to display only the 3rd row in the result. i.e., The result should look like below:

```
PID          OID      ITEM_PURCHASE_COUNT

93012594908 10021248    1
```

I tried using max, row_number,rank,dense_rank but I didn't get the correct result.

Need guidance on this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a

```
WHERE item_purchase_count = 1
```

Or are you trying to say you want the largest. Thus a qualify

```
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by pid, oid order by item_purchase_count desc ) = 1
```

thus:

```
SELECT 
    pid,
    oid,
    item_to_buy AS item_purchase_count
FROM (
    SELECT distinct 
        A.pid,
        A.oid,
        B.item_to_buy
    FROM table A
    JOIN table B
        ON A.product_id = B.product_id
    WHERE date='2022-03-03'
        AND A.oid IS NOT NULL
        AND A.oid = 34721248
)
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by pid, oid order by item_purchase_count desc ) = 1
```

OR actually:

```
SELECT distinct 
    A.pid,
    A.oid,
    B.item_to_buy AS item_purchase_count
FROM table A
JOIN table B
    ON A.product_id = B.product_id
WHERE date='2022-03-03'
    AND A.oid IS NOT NULL
    AND A.oid = 34721248
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by A.pid, A.oid order by item_purchase_count desc ) = 1
```

OR if you want to write it in long form:

```
SELECT 
    pid,
    oid,
    item_to_buy AS item_purchase_count
FROM (
    SELECT distinct 
        A.pid,
        A.oid,
        B.item_to_buy
        row_number() over (partition by A.pid, A.oid order by B.item_to_buy desc ) as rnk
    FROM table A
    JOIN table B
        ON A.product_id = B.product_id
    WHERE date='2022-03-03'
        AND A.oid IS NOT NULL
        AND A.oid=34721248
)
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

*helps if you partition the data, cell phones are not the best for writing answers on.. sigh*

Comment: I'm trying to say that I want to display the largest value.

Comment: I missed the `partition by A.pid, A.oid ` but you will want that

Comment: I will take care of that. Thank much :)